# Google API Reports don't get activities when change share option from Anyone at domain can find and access to Anyone at domain with the link can view

Tags: api, report

In my application I am using API REPORTS, precisely I am using following method: https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/reference/activities/list?authuser=1 for event "change_document_access_scope"

What is the problem?

1. On my google drive I have got document shared with option: **Anyone at domain can find and access**.
2. Next I am changing share option for this document to **Anyone at domain with the link can view**.

Now I am expecting that for event **change_document_access_scope** API REPORTS will return any activities, but I don't get anything, I get empty response:

```
{
  "kind": "admin#reports#activities",
  "etag": "\"90jXilLAoOTM3TlJpxWMBfdXYBM/uovIdT5Ey0q_14ilMH4jBscIlpo\""
}
```

I am testing method with Try this API https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/reference/activities/list?authuser=1 with following parameters:

userKey -> **all**

applicationName -> **drive**

eventName -> **change_document_access_scope**

startTime -> **2018-05-23T11:00:08.000Z**

the remaining fields are empty.

What is interesting:

When I am changing share option from **Anyone at domain can find and access** to **Anyone at domain with the link can edit** or **Anyone at domain with the link can comment** I get proper activities only when **I am changing from Anyone at domain can find and access** to **Anyone at domain with the link can view** I don't get proper activities.

Does anyone know why I am getting empty activities list ?

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

Have to use event **change_document_visibility** to get proper response when you change *acccess scope*/*visibility*  from **Anyone at domain can find and access** to **Anyone at domain with the link can view**.